# Why do we split improper integrals where both bounds are at infinity?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I know that when a function $f(x)$ has a discontinuity at some $x = c$, to calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$, you need to split the integral into two parts: $\int_{-\infty}^{c}f(x)dx + \int_{c}^{\infty}f(x)dx$.

However, if a function $f(x)$ does not have a discontinuity, why is this split still necessary?

Example: Calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\sin(x^2)dx$.

This integral diverges if we split it at some $x = c$, but if we calculate the integral without splitting it:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\sin(x^2) dx = \left. -\frac12 \cos(x^2) \right|_{-\infty}^{\infty} \\
= \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} -\frac12 \cos(x^2) - \lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} -\frac12 \cos(x^2) \\
= -\frac12(\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \cos(x^2) - \lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} \cos(x^2))
$$

Wouldn't this equal $0$ because $x^2$ would "strip" the negative from negative infinity, making it $-\frac12(\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \cos(x^2) - \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \cos(x^2))$?

Comment: No - $\cos u$ is periodic, even if $u = x^2.$ The limit at infinity doesn't exist!

Comment: When you ask this, maybe also report the reasons for this given in a calculus textbook.

Comment: $\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{-a}^a f(x)dx$ is called the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) of the improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that your integral is actually a double limit:
$$\lim_{a,b \to \infty} \int_{-a}^b f(x) dx.$$

To show that this limit exists, you have to show that regardless of the speeds at which $a$ and $b$ approach infinity, your integral will approach a single finite value.

What you are proposing to do is:
$$\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^a f(x) dx.$$

This is the case when both upper and lower limits approach infinity at the same speed which is far less strong than the above kind of integral.

Comment: In this particular case OP made the further mistake of splitting the "proposed" limit into two parts, neither of which is defined, but I think the fundamental error is as you say, making unwarranted assumptions about symmetry as the bounds of the integral go to $-\infty$ and $\infty$ respectively, so I agree with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the easiest way to understand this is to consider a very simple integral of this type.  Probably the simplest is
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\,dx\ .$$
Your argument is that the positive bits and the negative bits have the same size and therefore cancel each other out.  **But** both of these sizes are infinite, so this is essentially the same as claiming that $\infty-\infty=0$.  Definitely not true! - you cannot do arithmetic with $\infty$ as if it were a real number.

If you need more convincing about that last sentence, let me ask what you would say is $\infty+1$?  Probably you will say it is still $\infty$.  But if
$$\infty+1=\infty\ ,$$
**and if you claim that you can do arithmetic with $\infty$ according to "normal" rules"**, then we can subtract $\infty$ from both sides and get $1=0$.  I hope it's now clear that you can't do this kind of thing.

Final comment: if you know that an integral of this type converges (i.e., has a finite value), then you can calculate it in pretty much the way you suggest.  But only if you **already know** that it converges!

**Theorem**.  If $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx$ converges, then
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx=\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{-a}^a f(x)\,dx\ .$$

Comment: Interestingly, with nonstandard analysis, you actually can do arithmetic with $\inf$ mostly as if it were a number (although I use $\omega$ instead of $\inf$ to make the distinction).  It's just that $\omega + 1 \neq \omega$.  In fact, most strange things with infinities largely vanish under nonstandard analysis.  So, in other words, you *could* do arithmetic with $\inf$ as if it were a real number *if you always continued to treat it that way*.

Comment: @johnnyb I'm not an expert but when you say $\omega+1\ne\omega$, I believe you are thinking about ordinal arithmetic, which is not the same as non-standard real analysis.

Comment: Also, if you make the substitution $u=x-1$ you get $$0=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xdx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty(u+1)du=\infty.$$

Comment: @David - if I remember correctly, in ordinal arithmetic $1 + \omega = \omega$ but $\omega + 1 \neq \omega$, but in nonstandard analysis, neither one is equivalent.

Comment: @johnnyb Yes I believe that is correct, addition is not commutative.  Another reason why ordinal arithmetic is different from real arithmetic (whether standard or non-standard).  The point remains that you cannot use infinity in real arithmetic and expect it to obey normal algebraic rules (such as the existence of an additive inverse).

Comment: Addition *is* commutative in nonstandard analysis.  That was my point.  Essentially, in nonstandard analysis, arithmetic operations are valid and equivalent.

Comment: @johnnyb Yes that is **exactly what I said**.  (1) Addition is not commutative in ordinal arithmetic.  (2) Addition is commutative in real analysis, whether standard or non-standard.  (3) Therefore, you cannot treat infinity in real analysis the same way as you do in ordinal arithmetic.  Hope I have now made this 100% clear.